# Problema al agregar enlace a cada control LinkLabel en aplicación de escritorio

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo una aplicación c# de tipo [windows-forms](/questions/tagged/windows-forms) que cuenta con dos (2) *`LinkLabel`*; cada *`LinkLabel`* debe poseer el enlace para descargar un archivo Excel<sup>1</sup>.

El problema que tengo es que, al agregar el enlace de la ruta del archivo para cada *`LinkLabel`*, solo se aplica a uno de los dos enlaces.

La secuencia de pasos a seguir son las siguientes:

- Seleccione una opción de un control "ComboBox".
- De acuerdo a la selección, se mostrarán los dos *`LinkLabels`* que posee el formulario.
- Cuando se seleccione la opción "Mundo", debe aplicar a cada *`LinkLabel`* un enlace único:

Este es el código que utilizo *(código dentro del evento SelectedIndexChanged del ComboBox)*:

```
LinkLabel.Link ln = new LinkLabel.Link();

switch (cmb_softwareContable.Text.Trim())
{
    case "Mundo":

        // Primer LinkLabel:
        ln.LinkData = RutaPlt_Ventas;
        lnklbl_descargarPlantilla.Text = "Plant.Ventas";
        lnklbl_descargarPlantilla.Links.Add(ln);
        lnklbl_descargarPlantilla.Visible = true;
        ln.LinkData = null;

        // Segundo LinkLabel:       
        ln.LinkData = RutaPlt_Inventario;
        lnklbl_dwnPlnInvent.Links.Add(ln);
        lnklbl_dwnPlnInvent.Text = "Plant.Inventario";
        lnklbl_dwnPlnInvent.Visible = true;
        ln.LinkData = null;

        break;
}
```

El resultado de ejecutar este código es que al primer *`LinkLabel`* "lnklbl_descargarPlantilla" se le aplica el enlace del otro *`LinkLabel`* "lnklbl_dwnPlnInvent".

¿Cuál es la forma correcta de establecer los enlaces a los controles *`LinkLabel`*?

---

<sup>1</sup> El archivo Excel se encuentra en la carpeta contenedora del archivo ejecutable ".exe".

Comment: Creo que necesitarias crear un `LinkLabel.Link` independiente para cada control. Como lo tienes ahorita, ambos controles comparten el mismo enlace. Si lo modificas, el cambio se aplicará en ambos controles.

Comment: @sgorozco, te invito a responder a la pregunta :). He intentado varias combinaciones, pero sigo obteniendo los mismos resultados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de revisar con mas detalle mi código, he visto que hay 1 *`LinkLabel`* que posee el evento *`LinkClicked`* declarado.

Con esto en mente, he declarado el evento *`LinkClicked`* al otro *`LinkLabel`* y le he aplicado la lógica para que se active el enlace según lo declaro dentro del método *`LinkClicked`*.

Es decir, en lugar de agregar *`LinkData`* al control *`LinkLabel`* *(como lo estaba intentando hacer)*, opté por establecer el valor del enlace dentro del método *`LinkClicked`*.

Este es mi código después de hacer el cambio:

```
/// <summary>
/// 08/05/2017: Evento que se dispara al darle click al enlace "Plant. inventario".
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void lnklbl_dwnPlnInvent_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    // Inicializar variables.
    string rutaSeleccionada = "";

    try
    {
        if (lnklbl_dwnPlnInvent.Links.Count > 0)
        {
            // "RutaPlt_Inventario" es un string que contiene
            // la ruta del archivo Excel a descargar.
            rutaSeleccionada = RutaPlt_Inventario;
            nombreDeLaPlantilla = Path.GetFileName(rutaSeleccionada);

            #region Generar archivo plano.

            // Muestra un SaveFileDialog así el usuario puede guardar el archivo plano a generar.
            // Asignado a este botón.
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog1.FileName = nombreDeLaPlantilla;
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Plantilla de configuración (.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
            saveFileDialog1.Title = lnklbl_dwnPlnInvent.Text;

            // Mostrar la ventana de "Descargar plantilla".
            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                File.Copy(rutaSeleccionada, saveFileDialog1.FileName, true);
                MessageBox.Show("Plantilla de inventario descargada.", TITULO, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }

            #endregion
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex is FileNotFoundException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No se pudo encontrar el archivo '" + nombreDeLaPlantilla + "'.", TITULO, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```